# Random int64 and float64 numbers

Tags: python, random, numpy

I'm trying to generate random 64-bit integer values for integers and floats using Numpy, **within the entire range of valid values for that type**. To generate random 32-bit floats, I can use:

```
In [2]: np.random.uniform(low=np.finfo(np.float32).min,high=np.finfo(np.float32).max,size=10)
Out[2]: 
array([  1.47351436e+37,   9.93620693e+37,   2.22893053e+38,
        -3.33828977e+38,   1.08247781e+37,  -8.37481260e+37,
         2.64176554e+38,  -2.72207226e+37,   2.54790459e+38,
        -2.47883866e+38])
```

but if I try and use this for 64-bit numbers, I get

```
In [3]: np.random.uniform(low=np.finfo(np.float64).min,high=np.finfo(np.float64).max,size=10)
Out[3]: array([ Inf,  Inf,  Inf,  Inf,  Inf,  Inf,  Inf,  Inf,  Inf,  Inf])
```

Similarly, for integers, I can successfully generate random 32-bit integers:

```
In [4]: np.random.random_integers(np.iinfo(np.int32).min,high=np.iinfo(np.int32).max,size=10)
Out[4]: 
array([-1506183689,   662982379, -1616890435, -1519456789,  1489753527,
        -604311122,  2034533014,   449680073,  -444302414, -1924170329])
```

but am unsuccessful for 64-bit integers:

```
In [5]: np.random.random_integers(np.iinfo(np.int64).min,high=np.iinfo(np.int64).max,size=10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/tom/tmp/<ipython console> in <module>()

/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.so in mtrand.RandomState.random_integers (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:6640)()

/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.so in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:5813)()

OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int
```

Is this expected behavior, or should I report these as bugs in Numpy?

Comment: were you able to solve that in the end?

Answer (score 7):

For integers you could generate 2 32 bit random numbers and combine them:

```
a + (b << 32)
```

Comment: the generator can be  biaised.  with cyclic generators, a => b .

Comment: @B.M. why do you see it can be biased? is there a way to overcome the bias?

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that the code for `numpy.random.uniform()` does high-low calculation at some point, and the Inf stems from there.

Uniformly distributed integers are easy to generate as was shown. Uniformly distributed floating point numbers would require rather more careful thought.

As for reporting these oddities as bugs, I think you should do either that or post a message to the project mailing list. That way you'll at least find out what the developers think is reasonable behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it refers to the random seed call.  The simplest code I've got that falls into "Python int too large to convert to C long" is:

```
x = numpy.random.random_integers(2**64,size=(SIZE,)).astype(numpy.uint64)
```

numpy.**version**=1.5.0 here

Comment: `np.random.random_integers` is deprecated, use `np.random.randint(2**64, dtype=np.uint64)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the `random_numbers` method expects only 32-bit integers.

According to [ticket #555](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/555) random seeds can now be 64-bit as of version 1.1.0  I suggest downloading and installing the latest version of NumPy from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/).

Comment: Which version does it say it is?

Comment: np.__version__ gives 1.4.0.dev7539

Comment: Perhaps you should try using a more stable release?  The ticket simply spoke of random number seeding with 64-bit, perhaps its referring to a different random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old question, but there is a new answer in Python `3.6.3`:

```
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct  6 2017, 12:04:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxsize
9223372036854775807
>>> np.random.randint(sys.maxsize)
8550528944245072046
```