# Easiest way to generate random int64 array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to make random array of `int64` uniformly distributed in some range that is not within `int32` limits.

There is `randint` and `random_integers` but they work with `int32`; supplying big upper limit produces `high is out of bounds for int32`.

How do I generate random `int64` array with specified range?

Possible solutions:

- Use floats generator. Won't it have poor resolution in this case?
- Generate random bytes, interpret them as `int64` array and then normalize via `lower + x % (upper - lower)`. But do `int32` generation has same normalization? Doesn't it affect uniformity?

Didn't I miss some more concise and convenient ways?

Why do random methods only produce `float`s and `int32`?

Comment: If you use a cryptographically sound PRNG (`SystemRandom`, for instance) then your option B should be safe.

Comment: Related, and perhaps duplicate, but old and doesn't have any really *good* answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658808/random-int64-and-float64-numbers

Comment: I believe this problem has been fixed in recent releases. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6910

Answer (score 10):

### Edit:

**Using dtype on windows with numpy > 1.11.0:**

As **@John Y** suggestion, it seems possible to cast integers to the desired format using `dtype` as a named parameter with `np.random.randint`:

```
a = np.random.randint(2147483647, 9223372036854775807, size=3, dtype=np.int64)
```

**[end edit]**

You can generate an array directly by setting the range for randint; it is likely more efficient than a piecemeal generation and aggregation of an array:

**Docstring:** (numpy randint)

```
randint(low, high=None, size=None)
```

**size range if int 32:**

```
ii32 = np.iinfo(np.int32)
iinfo(min=-2147483648, max=2147483647, dtype=int32)
```

**size range for int64 <-> c long**

```
ii64 =  np.iinfo(np.int64)
iinfo(min=-9223372036854775808, max=9223372036854775807, dtype=int64)
```

**Generate an array of int64 of val > int32.max:**

```
a = np.random.randint(2147483647, 9223372036854775807, size = 3)
array([4841796342900989982,   43877033468085758,  205656391264979944])
```

**checking the type of the data:** gives `int64` as expected

```
a.dtype
dtype('int64')
```

numpy.randint gives you a uniform distribution across the specified range (**attention**, the range is exclusive of both ends, unlike python randint)

Comment: I just tried exactly the same and got `high is out of bounds for int32`. My configuration is Windows 7 64-bit, Python 3.4.3 32-bit, numpy 1.11.0.

Comment: Hummm... I unfortunately can't help you there, I don't have a windows machine, and my set up is with python 64 bits. (which may explain why it works)

Comment: I'll check it on 64-bit Python on Linux and Windows.

Comment: You may have to explicitly specify the `dtype` parameter to (NumPy's) `randint()`. On my system, I get `ValueError: high is out of bounds for int32` if I don't specify it. But `a = np.random.randint(2147483647, 9223372036854775807, size=3, dtype=np.int64)` works. Apparently, this parameter has not yet made it to the official documentation; the functionality was only added relatively recently (I think Jan 2016).

Comment: This is a great suggestion John Y. Interestingly, dtype throws: `TypeError: randint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'` on mac osx with python 64. Are you on a windows machine? Maybe that is the workaround numpy implemented to overcome windows int32?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows. I believe the `dtype` parameter is new for 1.11.0.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `random.randint` and convert the return value:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import random
>>> np.int64(random.randint(10000, 1000000000000))
321601597066
```

I can't guarantee that this is the *fastest* way to do it, but at least it works and is super clear ... (and to get an array, you just do this a bunch of times).

Comment: Indeed, that should work. I have to test how efficient it is.

Answer (score 6):

As Robert Kern already mentioned in the comments above, in the most recent release of numpy (v1.11.0) [`np.random.randint` accepts a `dtype=` parameter which allows you to generate 64-bit integers directly](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6910).

If you have an older version of numpy and for some reason you can't upgrade, your proposed solution of generating random bytes, viewing them as int64 and truncating them according to your desired range should be equally valid - <s>in fact, [that's essentially how numpy's internal RNG does it](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c#L275-L310)</s>*.

*As **@moarningsun** pointed out below `rk_random_uint64` actually uses rejection sampling, but I still see no reason not to wrap the values with a modulo.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

def randint64(low, high, size, seed=None):

    # generate a string of random bytes
    n = np.prod(size)
    bytes = np.random.RandomState(seed).bytes(n * 8)

    # view as an int64 array
    ints = np.fromstring(bytes, np.int64, n).reshape(size)

    ints %= np.int64(high - low)    # truncate
    ints += np.int64(low)           # offset

    return ints

imax = np.iinfo(np.int64).max
print(imax)
# 9223372036854775807

ints = randint64(0, imax, int(1E6), seed=0)

print(ints.max())
# 9223355891497906972

# test uniformity
print(stats.kstest(ints, stats.uniform(loc=0, scale=imax).cdf))
# KstestResult(statistic=0.00085961807556278469, pvalue=0.45082598256836681
```

Comment: In that Numpy code the values that are out of range are discarded, not wrapped around! I think the comment "The numbers wrap if rng is sufficiently large" refers to the unsigned addition `out[i] =  off + val;`.